# Changing individual column values for groups within a data set

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transformation

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Name    Difference  Status
A       2           No Action
A       1           No Action
B       3           No Action
B       5           No Action
C       4           No Action
C       1           No Action
```

For each group of `Name` within this data set, I am trying to set the value of the `Status` column to "Renewed" for the row with the lowest `difference` value.

```
Name    Difference  Status
A       2           No Action
A       1           Renewed
B       3           Renewed
B       5           No Action
C       4           No Action
C       1           Renewed
```

What would be the most optimal way of doing this for a large data set with additional columns. I thought of doing this with Groupby + Transform but couldn't figure out how to change individual column values for each group. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Difference'].idxmin(), 'Status'] = 'Renewed'`

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, it gives me a ValueError